# Is it "the city" or "the City" when colloquially referring to NYC?

Tags: capitalization, proper-nouns

People will refer to New York City as "the city" fairly often, but in writing should that be capitalized?

Comment: Depends.  If you live outside of NYC and you're going into town you'd tweet "I'm going into the city."  But if you live a bit farther away and you're going to do something you'd tweet "I'll be in the City (or perhaps The City) next week."  In the first case you're merely going to town, just as one might go from Lesser Podunk to Greater Podunk.  In the second case you're using a nickname for NYC.

Comment: To complicate matters, people who live in the so-called outer boroughs (the sections of NYC other than Manhattan) say they are *going to the city* when they mean *going to Manhattan* even though they are already in The City.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Strange as it may seem to New Yorkers, the use of "the city" to refer to their hometown is not by any means unique to them.  (By the way, I am one of those New Yorkers.)  If you have friends in Philadelphia, for example, or its surrounding area, you'll find they might say they're spending Saturday night in the city, and after a brief period of cogitation, you realize they aren't making the 90-minute drive to Manhattan.

This scenario holds true for any big city.  Therefore, I don't think that "the City" is a nickname, nor is it specific to New York.  I would suggest using lower-case, whether you're coming from Brooklyn or eastern Long Island.

By the way, the City of London is a specific district in the British capital, and references to that specific area should be capitalized.

Comment: I agree...the City is a term closely associated with the financial disctric of London, (I work in the City..clearly refers to that part of London).  as for NYC..the city that never sleeps comes to mind...buy no specific link between NYC and the City.

Comment: To people in the Bay area, San Francisco is "the city".  Istanbul, translated, is "the city" in Turkish.  New Yorkers tend to think that their city is the center of the universe.

Answer (score 0):

As a New Yorker, "The City" refers to NYC, specifically Manhattan.  It is a nickname, and therefore capitalized because it is a proper noun.  I agree that using "the city" when referring to the a metropolitan area is not unique, but would not be capitalized.  This could hold true about NYC when someone is just referring to the area (the city rather than the suburbs, for example) rather than calling it by its nickname.  Saying (or writing) "The City" when referring to NYC is more similar to people calling Philadelphia, "Philly". The distinction (obviously) comes in the written form.

Comment: It's actually pretty ambiguous. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_City) lists 5 places (not counting the fictional ones) associated with the term *the City*: the City of London (not to be confused with London, the capital of the UK), Manhattan, New York City, San Francisco and Oklahoma City.